# Unable to handle JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature with middleware

Tags: javascript, express, jwt

My middleware is unable to handle an error when `jwt.verify(request.token, process.env.SECRET)` raises `JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature with middleware` when an invalid token is sent even though I think I have set up my middleware properly. This error causes my app to crash.

Error occurs in the blogs.js file when trying add a new blog when using an invalid token:

blog.js:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const blogsRouter = require("express").Router();

const Blog = require("../models/blog");
const User = require("../models/user");

blogsRouter.post("/", async (request, response) => {
    const body = request.body;

    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(request.token, process.env.SECRET);
    if (!decodedToken.id) {
        return response.status(401).json({ error: "token invalid" });
    }
    const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id);

    const newBlog = new Blog({
        title: body.title,
        author: body.author,
        url: body.url,
        likes: body.likes || 0,
        user: user.id,
    });

    const savedBlog = await newBlog.save();
    user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog._id);
    await user.save();

    response.status(201).json(savedBlog);
});

module.exports = blogsRouter
```

middleware.js:

```
const unknownEndpoint = (request, response) => {
    response.status(404).send({ error: "unknown endpoint" });
};

const errorHandler = (error, request, response, next) => {
    logger.error(error.message);

    if (error.name === "CastError") {
        return response.status(400).send({ error: "malformatted id" });
    } else if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
        return response.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    } else if (error.name === "JsonWebTokenError") {
        return response.status(401).json({ error: "invalid token" });
    } else if (error.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
        return response.status(401).json({
            error: "token expired",
        });
    }
    
    next(error);
};

const tokenExtractor = (request, response, next) => {
    const authorization = request.get("authorization");
    if (authorization && authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        request.token = authorization.replace("Bearer ", "");
    }
    next()
}

module.exports = { requestLogger, unknownEndpoint, errorHandler, tokenExtractor };
```

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("./utils/config");
const logger = require("./utils/logger");
const middleware = require("./utils/middleware");

const blogsRouter = require("./controllers/blogs");
const usersRouter = require("./controllers/users");
const loginRouter = require("./controllers/login");

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

mongoose
    .connect(config.MONGODB_URI)
    .then(() => {
        logger.info("connected to MongoDB");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        logger.info("error connectig to MongoDB", error.message);
    });

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(middleware.tokenExtractor)

app.use("/api/blogs", blogsRouter);
app.use("/api/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/api/login", loginRouter);

app.use(middleware.errorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the jwt.verify call in a try-catch block and send the error message if the token is invalid.

```
blogsRouter.post("/", async (request, response) => {

        const body = request.body;
        try {
            const decodedToken = jwt.verify(request.token, process.env.SECRET);
            if (!decodedToken.id) {
                return response.status(401).json({ error: "token invalid" });
            }
            const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id);
    
            const newBlog = new Blog({
                title: body.title,
                author: body.author,
                url: body.url,
                likes: body.likes || 0,
                user: user.id,
            });
    
            const savedBlog = await newBlog.save();
            user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog._id);
            await user.save();
    
            response.status(201).json(savedBlog);
        } catch (e) {
            return response.status(401).json({ error: "token invalid" });
    
        }
    });
```